# Unable to use pip on Windows 7 and WinPython

Tags: python, pip, windows-7-x64

I am trying to get some work done with [pyAudioAnalysis](https://github.com/tyiannak/pyAudioAnalysis). I am running Eclipse Neon on Windows 7 x64. Since the "default" distro of Python didn't ship scientific packages i removed it and installed WinPython instead. Turns out pyAudioAnalysis also needs eyeD3 as an additional package, but when i call "pip install eyeD3" on the Windows Console the following error shows up:

```
"pip" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I thought the WinPython installation went wrong somewhere and forgot to add python to the system Path. I added both the location of python.exe and \Scripts\pip.exe, but the same error is shown. I remember trying also with the "vanilla" Python install and it didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: This is more of a pip and PATH problem, not related to pyaudio. Have you restarted the command prompt since you changed the PATH? Does pip work if you pass it the exact location, instead of `pip install`, try `path/to/pip.exe install`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @TankorSmash. Yes, I restarted the command prompt. Actually, I also tried to launch pip with the absolute path and pip answered with "Fatal error in launcher: unable to create process using ' " '. I tried to google that to no avail.

Comment: Have you looked at all the results? https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1997

Answer (score 3):

maybe try this:

- click on the Winpython icon "WinPython Command Prompt.exe"
- then type "pip install eyeD3"

Answer (score 2):

I too had faced the issue after moving to  WinPython, the steps I followed to make it similar to regular python installation are the following:

1. Added my WinPython path (`C:\ProgramFiles\WPy-3670\python-3.x.x\`) to System Variable->Path (running python command globally).
2. Using the `python -m pip install package-name` to install the required package easily.